# Woocommerce: function to check if the cart contains any product

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce, product, cart

On Wordpress, I'm trying to set a condition for displaying a widget if the woocommerce cart contains at least one product (**any**). I'm not sure which code to use, if anyone would like to help me out, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help:

```
if(WC()->cart && !WC()->cart->is_empty()){
    // the cart has products
}
```